# installing a .deb package

Tags: package, install

I am a new eOS user and I can't find a particular application in the store. Do I need to do anything in particular before trying to install directly from .deb file?

Answer (score 5):

You can give [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/) a try if you prefer a nice graphical interface.

Comment: Would definitely recommend Eddy

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with the command line, you can use the `dpkg` command to install a .deb package.

The format would be `sudo dpkg -i name_of_package.deb`

then, `sudo apt-get install -f`. the `dpkg -i` command may leaves the package status in an "unconfigured" state due to missing dependencies.
`sudo apt-get install -f` will try to fix it downloading and installing those dependencies

If you're looking for a graphical install, you can use the Software Center or the Gdebi application.

This website might help you:
https://itsfoss.com/install-deb-files-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395?newreg=39aad30029724c7693799c0ff875d95c

All the Best,

- Tony